# Return dataframe rows where the values in a column are not of type date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like:

```
 Name   Date of birth
  Bob   
Steve      22/07/1963
   Jo          pencil
Karen      03/02/1953
Frank      29/09/1994
```

Is there a way to return rows where `Date of birth` is not a date?

In the above example I would have returned:

```
 Name   Date of birth
  Bob   
   Jo          pencil
```

Where `Date of birth` is not a date.

I can identify where there is a blank value for Date of birth using:

```
missingDoBError = df.loc[df['Date of birth'].isnull()]
```

I have tried to find Date of birth values where the value is not a date format at set to NaT by using:

```
if pd.to_datetime(df['Date of birth'], format='%d-%b-%Y', errors='coerce').notnull().all():
```

But I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need change format to `%d/%m/%Y` and test missing values:

```
m2 = pd.to_datetime(df['Date of birth'], format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce').isnull()
#or skip parameter format if performance is not important
#m2 = pd.to_datetime(df['Date of birth'], errors='coerce').isnull()

df = df[m2]
print (df)
  Name Date of birth
0  Bob           NaN
2   Jo        pencil
```

If want omit `NaN`s rows chain another boolean mask for test not missing values with bitwise `AND` (`&`):

```
m1 = df['Date of birth'].notnull()
m2 = pd.to_datetime(df['Date of birth'], format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce').isnull()

df = df[m1 & m2]
print (df)
  Name Date of birth
2   Jo        pencil
```

Comment: I think we can skip the format. Let pandas decide for us what is a date and what not (I mean).

Comment: Pandas isn't about performance always. I think it is more about quick data exploration. If we pass a format and there is a date in %Y-%m-%d we would miss it. But maybe OP is strict about the format.

Comment: @AntonvBR - I agree, if want general solution better is omit it, if only same format and  important is performance, better is use it. ;)

Comment: Exactly what I meant! Nice solution anwyay.